# TypeError: 'Pagination' object is not iterable in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table with data(s). I want to get the result set with pagination in API response.

I am using the `GET` method to call API. Here is the

Requirement:

1. Need to page number and number of data
2. pagination data with previous and next URL(s)

My Code :

```
@api.route('/', methods=["GET"])
@app.route('/page/<int:page>')
class List(Resource):
    """USER data(s)"""

    def get(self, page=1):
        """GET Lists"""
        all_data = User.query.paginate(page, per_page=2)
        result = user_serializer.dump(all_data)
        return result
```

Issue:

TypeError: 'Pagination' object is not iterable in Flask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with your code is you are trying to pass the `Pagination` object to your `serializer`. Instead what the serializer expects is either a list of model instances or a single model instance. Just change your call to this

```
result = user_serializer.dump(all_data.items)
```

Sources

1. https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination

Answer (score 2):

I added `.items` in the for loop of the jinja template and it worked.

Example

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
  {% for user in users.items %}
    <article class="media content-section mt-4">
      <img class="rounded-circle" article-img src="">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ user.first_name }}</a>
          <small class="text-muted"></small>
        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href=""></a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```